# ImageView always scaling beyond scene size, can't seem to force it to fit

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFX (been working with swing for a long time) and am trying to work with BorderPane. One would assume BorderPane is similar to BorderLayout but the big difference is the center of BorderPane will expand to fit its contents while BorderLayout will shrink to fit the window.

I am using JFXPanel in a JFrame and have a 3 part interface: A panel on the left (some text), some buttons on the bottom (flow control), and in the center want to have a dynamic panel/pane, that for the most part will be just an imageview. I set it all up and it works fine, but I'm working with camera images here which are way bigger than my monitor. I've tried scaling the images down by binding the imageview width to different things (such as anchor pane, scene size (works, but not properly), etc. The issue I am having is that since borderpane's center panel expands to fit its content, it will expand and never have a proper value I can bind to. I need the image to be fully visible in the window at any size.

Here's the code I've been working with.

```
protected void setupFXWindow(JFXPanel mainPanel) {
    butNext = new Button("Next Step");
    butBack = new Button("PreviousStep Step");
    butQuit = new Button("Cancel Signature Generation");
    butNext.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Next step..."));
    butBack.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Previous Step..."));
    butQuit.setTooltip(new Tooltip("Quit generating a signature"));

    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, javafx.scene.paint.Color.ALICEBLUE);

    javafx.scene.image.Image fximage = new javafx.scene.image.Image(new File(image.getSourceFilePath()).toURI().toString());
    ImageView iv1 = new ImageView();
    iv1.setImage(fximage);
    iv1.setPreserveRatio(true);
    VBox directionsPanel = new VBox();
    HBox authorflowPanel = new HBox(); //bottom buttons for next, back, etc.
    mainPanel.setScene(scene);

    //INSTRUCTIONS
    directionsStepLabel = new Text();
    directionsLabel = new Text();
    setDirectionsText("Directions will be placed here.");
    exampleLabel = new Text("Example");
    exampleIconLabel = new Text("An example image will be shown here.");

    directionsPanel.setPadding(new javafx.geometry.Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
    directionsPanel.getChildren().addAll(directionsStepLabel, directionsLabel, exampleLabel);

    authorflowPanel.getChildren().addAll(butBack, butQuit, butNext);

    BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
    bp.prefHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
    bp.prefWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
    bp.setLeft(directionsPanel);
    bp.setBottom(authorflowPanel);
    bp.setCenter(iv1);
    root.getChildren().add(bp);
}
```

This code sample doesn't have iv1 (imageview) binded to anything, cause at this point I have no idea what I can bind to that will give me the remaining space in the scene. Since I cannot use the full width or height of the scene, I'm at a loss of what I am supposed to do here.

The code above makes it look like this:

[image: overexpanding image]

Comment: Would you try with this?
`iv1.setFitWidth(fximage.getWidth());`
This may work.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `ImageView` in some kind of `Pane` (e.g. a `StackPane`). Then the pane will fill the center region of the border pane and you can bind to its width and height:

```
ImageView iv1 = new ImageView();
iv1.setImage(fximage);
iv1.setPreserveRatio(true);
StackPane imageContainer = new StackPane(iv1);
iv1.fitWidthProperty().bind(imageContainer.widthProperty());
iv1.fitHeightProperty().bind(imageContainer.heightProperty());

// ...

bp.setCenter(imageContainer);
```

Comment: That works, but I need to keep its aspect ratio. When using the keep aspect ratio attribute, it goes back to full size again.